# Creating a matrix of coefficients from coef function in R

Tags: r, extract, glm

From this code:

```
    treatment     <- factor(rep(c(1, 2), c(43, 41)), 
                        levels = c(1, 2),
                        labels = c("placebo", "treated"))
improved      <- factor(rep(c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3), c(29, 7, 7, 13, 7, 21)),
                        levels = c(1, 2, 3),
                        labels = c("none", "some", "marked"))    
numberofdrugs <- rpois(84, 10) + 1    
healthvalue   <- rpois(84, 5)   
y             <- data.frame(healthvalue, numberofdrugs, treatment, improved)
test          <- glm(healthvalue~numberofdrugs+treatment+improved + treatment:improved, y, family=poisson)
summary(test)
```

we get the following using the coef() function:

```
> coef(test)
                    (Intercept)                   numberofdrugs                treatmenttreated 
                    1.549172817                     0.004261529                     0.014634807 
                   improvedsome                  improvedmarked   treatmenttreated:improvedsome 
                    0.201150827                    -0.129251907                    -0.258841251 
treatmenttreated:improvedmarked 
                    0.051326071
```

I wish to arrange the coefficients of the variables into vectors and the coefficients of the interactions into a matrix, to be able to more easily work with them.

For example:

```
coef.intercept=(1.5491)

coef.numberofdrugs=(0.00426)

coef.treatment=(0, 0.01463)

coef.improved=(0, 0.2011, -0.1292)
```

and a correlation matrix with treatment as rows and improved as columns, like this:

coef.correlation=

```
(0       0       0  )

(0  -0.2588  -0.2588)
```

Is there any efficient way to do this?

Note that any of the coefficients that are not listed in coef() function shall be set to zero and I have shortened some of the numbers above.

Comment: write a function? this doesn't seem like a common thing to do. Like, why is it more easy to work with four objects instead of one? Also, those are interaction terms not correlations

Comment: Sorry, interaction terms.

Comment: I want to do this to manually predict in R, instead of using the predict() function. So I would prefer to create a matrix of the interaction coefficients...

Comment: How can you write a function if you cannot call the desired interaction terms which coef() or summary() produces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `allEffects` from the `effects` package may be of interest:

```
library(effects)
allEffects(test)
 model: healthvalue ~ numberofdrugs + treatment + improved + treatment:improved

 numberofdrugs effect
numberofdrugs
       6        8       10       12       14       16       18       20 
4.050962 4.322559 4.612365 4.921601 5.251570 5.603662 5.979360 6.380247 

 treatment*improved effect
         improved
treatment     none     some   marked
  placebo 4.416773 3.713517 5.461153
  treated 4.596433 4.902746 5.309627
```

Comment: Looks like I just have to write a function

Comment: There got to be a way to "call" specific interaction coefficients... how else should predict() function do this?

Comment: I figured it out: use as.list(coef(test)) and you are able to call desired coefficients and therefore create a matrix.